# How to load the Physics data on the server side in a multi-player game

Tags: game-physics, ogre, bulletphysics

i use Ogre for rendering stuff and Bullet for physics stuff. in my client, `.secene` and `.mesh` file creates the terrain. on the client side, i can add some code to the `DotSceneLoader.hpp` and create physics object while it is processing methods such as `processEntity()`.

but i don't know how to get the physics data on my server side, because there is no need to load rendering stuff. the question is, when i only have the `.secene` and `.mesh` file, how can i create my physics object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i get the answer from ogre forums, http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Bullet_binary_serialization